# Solve $3 = -x^2+4x$ by factoring

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I have $3 = -x^2 + 4x$ and I need to solve it by factoring. According to wolframalpha the solution is $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 3$.
\begin{align*}
 3 & = -x^2 + 4x\\
 x^2-4x+3 & = 0
\end{align*}

According to wolframalpha $(x-3) (x-1) = 0$ is the equation factored, which allows me to solve it, but how do I get to this step?

Comment: Put in standard form. Factor. Set each factor equal to zero. http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factquad.htm

Comment: Do you know any factoring method?

Comment: From $x^2 - 4x + 3 =0$ you can use the quadratic formula to get $x=3,1$. Then you know that the polynomial can be written as $(x-3)(x-1)$. Alternatively, you can look for two numbers $r_1, r_2$, such that $r_1r_2=3$ and $r_1+r_2=-4$. Assuming that the roots will be integers makes solving these equations simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You moved everything onto the same side of the equation, which is a great start!

The next step is to understand factorization of quadratic polynomials.

Suppose you have a polynomial of the form

$$x^2 + cx + d \tag{1} $$

You want something of the form

$$ (x+a)(x+b) $$

When you expand out $(x+a) (x+b)$, you get
$$ (x+a)(x+b) = x^2 + (a+b)x + ab \tag{2}$$

Now, when we compare the coefficients of (2) to (1), we see that

$$ a+b = c $$
$$ ab = d $$

That is, we need to find two numbers $a$ and $b$ that add up to $c$ and multiply into $d$.

In our case, $c$ is -4 and $d$ is 3. Now we have to think about it for a bit and do a bit of guessing and checking, but you should be able to see that $a=-3$ and $b =-1$ meets this criteria.

-3+(-1) = -4, and (-3)*(-1)=3.

Comment: Rather than guessing, we could list the ways to factor $3$, then choose the pair of numbers that have sum $-4$.  \begin{align*} 3 & = 1 \cdot 3 & 3 = \color{blue}{-1 \cdot -3} \end{align*}

Comment: It works in this case because the answer is nice enough that $a$ and $b$ are integers.  However, this isn't always true.  There are tricks to help you find $a$ and $b$ (i.e., if $c$ is negative but $d$ is positive, then $a$ and $b$ should both be negative), but I didn't want to make my post too long.

Comment: Despite my criticism, I consider your post the best answer I have read to this point.

Answer (score 1):

Move everything to one side then factor.  Factoring something like this is just trial and error.  You need to find two numbers whose product is $3$ and whose sum is $-4$.  So poking around a bit you should come up with $-3$ and $-1$.  So it factors as:
$x^2-4x+3=(x-3)(x-1)$

Comment: It is most certainly **not** "trial and error"! By listing each factor pair of $a \cdot c$, we can correctly identify the factors without fail.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Of course it can be done systematically, but for one that simple trial and error gets you there.

Comment: We can only find the factors this way if they involve rational numbers.  Of course, a problem stated like this is likely rigged to involve rational numbers.

Comment: @GEdgar True, and last time I checked $-1$ and $-3$ are rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar problem. Let's solve $$x^2 + 6 = 7x$$ by factoring.

First, we need to write this in [standard form](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/quadratic-equation.html): $$x^2 - 7x + 6 = 0$$

Then we seek two numbers whose *sum* is $-7$, and whose *product* is $6$. The two such numbers are $-1$ and $-6$.

At this point, you could just jump straight to $(x - 1)(x-6) = 0$, but if you have never seen this before, it might help to **rewrite the middle term** and factor by grouping. To wit:

$$x^2 - 7x + 6 = x^2 -1x - 6x + 6$$

We then write this as $$x(x-1) -6(x-1) = (x-6)(x-1)$$

From here, we set each factor equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Solving by factoring means reducing the polynomial to a lower degree by dividing it by factors $(x-x_i)$ for already known roots $x_i$.

The reason for this is that the lower degree polynomial might be easier to solve. Here this is not necessary, as a order $2$ polynomial is already solvable with moderate effort.

How to know roots? For this kind of task one should always try the $0, \pm 1, \pm 2$, which here gives $x_1 = 1$.

What is left is the division:
\begin{align}
& x^2 - 4x + 3 : x - 1 = x - 3 \\
-&(x^2-x) \\
= & -3x+3 = -3(x-1)
\end{align}
So we have the factored polynomial $(x+1)(x-3)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 3 = -x^2 +4x \implies \ x^2 -4x+3 = 0$$

$$ x^2 - 3x - x +3 = 0$$

$$ x(x-3)-1(x-3)$$
$$ (x-3)(x-1) = 0$$
$$x = 1, x = 3$$

For more on the methods, visit this [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/algebra/quadequationshirev1.shtml).

Alternatively, you could use the quadratic formula:

$$x =  \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

This was obtained from the quadratic equation:

$$ax^2 + bx +c = 0$$
where $a = 1, b = -4, c = 3$

Answer (score 0):

$$3=-x^2+4x$$ is equivalent to $$x^2-4x+3=0$$
wich is a quadratic equation, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are there solutions, we know that $$x^2-4x+3=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=0$$ where $$x_1+x_2=-(-4)$$
and $$x_1*x_2=3$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}x^2-4x+3&=x^2-3x-x+3\\
&=x(x-3)-(x-3)\\
&=(x-1)(x-3)
\end{align}

Note: You could also see that the sum of coefficients is zero, hence one root is $x=1$. Now divide the quadratic by $x-1$ to get the other factor.

Comment: Why are we suggesting *polynomial division* to a student who can't factor the simplest expression?!

Comment: I agree. But then a student can be defined as a learning machine :-)

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-4x+3 = 0$ is a quadratic equation; it can be factored as $(x - x_1)\cdot(x - x_2)$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots. The roots of the general quadratic equation are $x_{1,2} = \frac{-p \pm\sqrt{p^2 - 4q}}{2}$.

In this case the coefficients are $p = -4$ and $q = 3$.
$$\Rightarrow x_{1} = \frac{-p + \sqrt{p^2 - 4q}}{2} = 3,\  x_{2} = \frac{-p - \sqrt{p^2 - 4q}}{2} = 1$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2-4x+3 = (x - 3) \dot (x - 1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:
$$\begin{align}x^2-4x+3&=x^2-4x+4-1\\
&=(x-2)^2-1\\
&=(x-2-1)(x-2+1)\\
&=(x-3)(x-1)
\end{align}$$